# Add selected rows from an existing Pandas DataFrame to a new Pandas DataFrame in for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, iteration

I want to select some rows based on a condition from an existing Pandas DataFrame and then insert it into a new DataFrame.
At frist, I tried this way:

```
second_df = pd.DataFrame()
for specific_idx in specific_idx_set:
    second_df = existing_df.iloc[specific_idx]
len(specific_idx_set), second_df.shape => (1000), (15,)
```

As you see, I'm iterating over a set which has 1000 indexes. However, after I add these 1000 rows to into a new Pandas DataFrame(second_df), I saw only one of these rows was stored into the new DataFrame while I expected to see 1000 rows with 15 columns in this DataFrame.
So, I tried new way:

```
specific_rows = list() 
for specific_val in specific_idx_set:
    specific_rows.append( existing_df[existing_df[col] == specific_val])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(specific_rows)
```

And I got this error:

> ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1000, 1, 15)

Then, I wrote this code:

```
specific_rows = list() 
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for specific_val in specific_idx_set:
    specific_rows.append(existing_df[existing_df[col] == specific_val])
pd.concat([new_df, specific_rows])
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modify your last solution - remove empty DataFrame and for `concat` use list of DataFrames only:

```
specific_rows = list() 
for specific_val in specific_idx_set:
    specific_rows.append(existing_df[existing_df[col] == specific_val])
    
out = pd.concat(specific_rows)
```

Problem of your solution - if join list with DataFrame error is raised:

```
pd.concat([new_df, specific_rows])
#specific_rows - is list
#new_df - is DataFrame
```

If need append DataFrame need join lists - append one element list `[new_df]` + another list `specific_rows` - ouput is list of DataFrames:

```
pd.concat([new_df] + specific_rows)
```

Comment: I mentioned that I tried this way and I got an error. Also, I wrote the error that I got.

Comment: @Sara - I changed last solution from `pd.concat([new_df, specific_rows])` to `out = pd.concat(specific_rows)` and removed `new_df = pd.DataFrame()`, can you test it?

Comment: @amirhosseinnazary - No, because no data of OP.

Comment: Now, I removed the empty dataframe as well and my problem is solved. thanks

Comment: @jezrael -  Can you tell me more about the reason that I got error when I wrote empty dataframe and I mentioned both in pd.concat?